# Make non-Apple mouse scroll smoothly

Tags: mouse, macos

I've begun using a [Logitech G600](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gaming-mice/g600-mmo-gaming-mouse.html#910-002864) and customizing it with [Folivora](https://folivora.ai/), and the power of the combination is incredible. It's speeding up my workflow and making it more intuitive.

However... I miss the smooth scrolling of my Magic Mouse/Trackpad something awful. The jerky, clicking, jumpy scrolling really grates on me.

Is there a way to somehow make my non-Apple mouse scroll smoothly?

Comment: What you gain is balanced by what you loose... what settings have you considered to make it smoother.

Comment: The tool below helps. I'd say 'smooth experience' here would mean the page scrolls with a consistent perception when comparing macbook trackpad with a mouse you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a bit more digging I found a free and Open Source [tool that provides smooth scrolling on non-Apple mice](https://github.com/Caldis/Mos/blob/master/README.enUS.md).

Note you may have to [allow the application in File Quarantine](https://github.com/Caldis/Mos/wiki/If-the-App-not-work-properly) for it to run.

Comment: Free and Opensource ❤️